# Unable to mock WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to use the below class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/v2/api-docs", 
                "/swagger-resources/**",  
                "/swagger-ui.html", 
                "/webjars/**" ,
                "/swagger.json").permitAll();
        
    }

    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
    
}
```

to enable cors

When trying to write my Junit

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class WebConfigTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private WebConfig webConfig;

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = Mockito.mock(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);


    @Mock
    private HttpSecurity http;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConfigure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(http);
        System.out.println(webConfig);
    }
}
```

`WebConfig` and `HttpSecurity` are getting mocked, please suggest

Comment: So what class do you try to mock here and is not working, the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`?

Comment: WebConfig and HttpSecurity are getting mocked,